# How to get to a particular page in dbpedia using sparql query?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have a URI for a person, e.g., `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ashok_Gehlot` (which, when retrieved via HTTP, redirects to `http://dbpedia.org/page/Ashok_Gehlot`). I want to extract information about this resource. How could I write a SPARQL query to retrieve, e.g., Ashok Gehlot's birthdate?  In the following query (my attempt so far) what would I need to replace `????` with?

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>
PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX freebase: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX http: <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#>
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE {
  ?x ?????? http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ashok_Gehlot.
  ?x owl:birthdate ?z.
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't want properties of a page, you want propreties of  aresource.  In this case, the resource is `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ashok_Gehlot>`.  RDF is a graph based data representation, and a SPARQL query is a graph based query language.  You're looking for an edge of the graph whose source is `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ashok_Gehlot>`, whose edge label is `owl:birthdate` (which doesn't make sense, but that's a different issue), and you want to retrieve the other end of the edge and bind its value to the variable `?z`.  Thus, your query would be:

```
select ?z where { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ashok_Gehlot> owl:birthdate ?z
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?z%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Ashok_Gehlot%3E%20owl%3abirthdate%20?z%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Of course, that query has no results, because the resource has no property `owl:birthdate`.  If you browse the data that you see at [Ashok Gehlot](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ashok_Gehlot), you'll notice that there *are*:

- dbpedia-owl:birthDate 1951-05-03 (xsd:date)
- dbpprop:birthDate     3 (xsd:integer)
- dbpprop:dateOfBirth   1951 (xsd:integer)

The dbpedia-owl data is much cleaner than the dbpprop data, so you should use it.  Also noting that the prefix `dbpedia:` abbreviates `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>`, your query should be:

```
select ?birthDate where { 
  dbpedia:Ashok_Gehlot dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?birthDate%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aAshok_Gehlot%20dbpedia-owl%3abirthDate%20?birthDate%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
--------------
| birthDate  |
|============|
| 1951-05-03 |
--------------
```

If, for some reason, it really is important to have a query that's more in the shape of your original attempt, you could use the following.  The pattern `?x owl:sameAs? dbpedia:Ashok_Gehlot` means that `?x` will be bound to things that are zero or one step away from `dbpedia:Ashok_Gehlot` by the property `owl:sameAs`.  For the zero step case, `?x` is just `dbpedia:Ashok_Gehlot`, which is what you want.  For the one case, `?x` will be anything that is `owl:sameAs dbpedia:Ashok_Gehlot`, which should also be OK.

```
select ?birthDate where { 
  ?x owl:sameAs? dbpedia:Ashok_Gehlot .
  ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?birthDate%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?x%20owl%3asameAs?%20dbpedia%3aAshok_Gehlot%20.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpedia-owl%3abirthDate%20?birthDate%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)